# Gstreamer Bus internal data flow error

Tags: gstreamer

I am getting an error while receiving video from udpsource on client side:

```
        (Recievr:13885): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_get_structure: assertion `GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed

        (Recievr:13885): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_structure_get_fraction: assertion `structure != NULL' failed

        (Recievr:13885): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_get_structure: assertion `GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed

        (Recievr:13885): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_structure_get_fraction: assertion `structure != NULL' failed
        BUS CALL Internal data flow error.
        Returned, stopping playback
        Deleting pipeline
    Here is my code: where I tried to receive video over udp and parallely to display the video. I am using gstreamer-0.10.29 with RHEL-6.5 and forced to work with same version only.Can anybody tell me where is the problem or plz solve my problem.

                                           Client.c        

        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <gst/gst.h>
```

Here defining the bus

```
        gboolean bus_call(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, void *data) 
        { 
            gchar           *debug; 
            GError          *err; 
            GMainLoop       *loop = (GMainLoop*)data;         
            switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg)) 
            { 
                case GST_MESSAGE_APPLICATION: 
                    g_print("APP received on OBJ NAME %s\n",GST_OBJECT_NAME(msg->src)); 
                    break; 
                case GST_MESSAGE_EOS: 
                    g_print("EOS received on OBJ NAME %s\n",GST_OBJECT_NAME(msg->src)); 
                    g_main_loop_quit (loop); 
                    break; 
                case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: 
                    gst_message_parse_error(msg, &err, &debug); 
                    g_free(debug); 
                    g_print("BUS CALL %s\n", err->message); 
                    g_error_free(err); 
                    g_main_loop_quit (loop); 
                    break; 
                default: 
                    break; 
            } 
            return TRUE; 
        }         
        int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
        { 
            GMainLoop *loop; 
            gst_init(&argc,&argv); 

            loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);             
            GstElement  *pipeline, *vsource, *vtee, *vqueue, *tover, *xvsink, *evqueue, *vencoder, *muxer, *filesink; 
            GstCaps *filtercaps;
            GstBin      *recording; 
            GstBus      *bus; 
            GstPad      *srcpad,*sinkpad; 
           gint width, height, num, denom;
           const GstStructure *str;

          // Create gstreamer elements 
            pipeline   = gst_pipeline_new ("Live Recording"); 
            vsource    = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsrc","rtpsrc"); 
            vtee       = gst_element_factory_make ("tee", "viewing-tee"); 
            vqueue     = gst_element_factory_make ("queue2","viewing-queue"); 
          // vqueue     = gst_element_factory_make ("queue","viewing-queue"); 
            tover      = gst_element_factory_make ("timeoverlay","viewing-overlay"); 
  xvsink  = gst_element_factory_make ("xvimagesink","viewing-vsink");       

           GstElement  *filter, *vrate, *encoder, *conv, *sink;     

           recording  = GST_BIN(gst_bin_new("recording-bin")); 
       evqueue    = gst_element_factory_make ("queue2","encoding-queue");    
           vrate = gst_element_factory_make ("videorate", "video-rate");
           filter = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "filter");
           conv = gst_element_factory_make ("ffmpegcolorspace","converter");
           vencoder = gst_element_factory_make ("ffdec_mpeg4","mpeg-decoder");
           g_assert(vencoder);
         // sink = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsink","audio-output");        
           if(!pipeline || !vsource || !xvsink || !tover ) 
            { 
                g_print("Unable to create all necessary elements\n"); 
                return -1; 
            } 

          filtercaps = gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw-yuv","width", G_TYPE_INT, 640,"height", G_TYPE_INT, 480,"framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1, NULL);        
        g_assert(filtercaps);         

           g_object_set (G_OBJECT (filter), "caps", filtercaps, NULL);
           gst_caps_unref (filtercaps);        

          // g_object_set (G_OBJECT (vencoder), "bitrate" , 384 ,  NULL);
           //g_object_set (G_OBJECT (sink), "host" , "127.0.0.1" ,  NULL);
           g_object_set (G_OBJECT (vsource), "port" , 8999 ,  NULL);
          // g_object_set (G_OBJECT (sink), "async" , FALSE ,  NULL);

            bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline)); 
            gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop); 
            gst_object_unref (bus); 

           /* g_object_set(G_OBJECT(vsource), "num-buffers",300, NULL); 
            g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filesink),"location","output.avi", NULL);     
            g_object_set (G_OBJECT (tover), "halign", "right", NULL); 
            g_object_set (G_OBJECT (tover), "valign", "top", NULL); 
            g_object_set (G_OBJECT (tover), "shaded-background", TRUE, NULL); 
        */
          /* create the recording bin */ 

          //  gst_bin_add_many (recording, evqueue, vencoder, muxer, filesink, NULL); 
            //  gst_bin_add_many (recording, evqueue,vrate,filter,conv,vencoder, sink, NULL);//To be open
        gst_bin_add_many (recording, evqueue,vrate,filter,conv,vencoder, NULL);// ToBe remove for testing only     

            sinkpad       = gst_element_get_static_pad(evqueue,"sink"); 
            GstPad *ghost = gst_ghost_pad_new("vsink",sinkpad); 

            if(ghost == NULL) 
            {
                g_error("Unable to create ghostpad!\n"); 
            }            
            gst_element_add_pad(GST_ELEMENT(recording),ghost); 
            gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(sinkpad));     
       // gst_element_link_many(evqueue,vencoder,muxer,filesink,NULL); 
            gst_element_link_many(evqueue,vrate,filter,conv,vencoder, sink,NULL);         
            gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), vsource, vtee, vqueue, tover, xvsink, recording, NULL);             
            /* link video elements */ 
            gst_element_link_many(vsource,tover,vtee,NULL); 
            srcpad  = gst_element_get_request_pad(vtee,"src0"); 
            sinkpad = gst_element_get_pad(vqueue,"sink"); 
            gst_pad_link(srcpad,sinkpad); 
            gst_element_link(vqueue,xvsink); 

            /* link the viewing pipeline into the bin */ 
            srcpad  = gst_element_get_request_pad(vtee,"src1"); 
            sinkpad = gst_element_get_pad(GST_ELEMENT(recording),"vsink"); 
            gst_pad_link(srcpad,sinkpad);               
             g_print ("Running...\n");                 gst_element_set_state(pipeline,GST_STATE_PLAYING);             
           /*  str = gst_caps_get_structure (filtercaps, 0);
           if (!gst_structure_get_int (str, "width", &width) || !gst_structure_get_int (str, "height", &height) || 
               !gst_structure_get_fraction (str, "framerate", &num, &denom))             
                 g_print ("No width/height available\n");
           g_print ("The video size of this set of capabilities is %dx%d and the frame rate is %d/%d\n", width, height, num, denom);
        */
            g_main_loop_run (loop); 

            /* Out of the main loop, clean up nicely */ 
            g_print ("Returned, stopping playback\n"); 
            gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL); 
            g_print ("Deleting pipeline\n"); 
            gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));             
            return 0; 
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get a "*-CRITICAL" message, there is a simple recipe to drill down:

```
G_DEBUG="fatal_criticals" gdb --args ./your_app
```

then in gdb, 'r' to run it and when it crashed, type 'bt' to get a backtrace. For top-down for the first line in your code and fix it.